# issues with HiltViewModel context and inflate in onCreateViewHolder

Tags: kotlin, android-context, android-viewholder, dagger-hilt

I am trying to create a RecyclerView using Hilt, but I am new to Kotlin so I am making a couple mistakes with context and .inflate. I am unsure why these problems persist because I have looked at several models and seen similar code.

I have created a gist with my Fragment, here- https://gist.github.com/mspaldingworks/492f29af0e44701c29f8c8a4b3ca492e

The errors occur in fun onCreateViewHolder in lines 52, 53:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(patent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SessionViewHolder {             

val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)            
val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_list, parent, false)             

return SessionViewHolder(itemView)        
}
```

Looking into the problems I see

Unresolved reference: context :52

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: ... :53

I have been beating my head against the wall for a while trying to figure out the steps to correct these errors.

This will be my first post here, but I have scoured the stack and couldn't find a pattern with a problem similar to my own, so please forgive a newbie any posting faux pas or unintentionally omitted crucial information I might inadvertently have made. Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration of the parameters of this function, you wrote `patent` instead of `parent`, so in your code below it doesn't know what you're talking about when you put `parent`

Comment: omg, that was it!  Thank you so much!! I've stared at tutorials and samples and everything I could find!  Well, I guess researching was a good way to spend 48 hrs...